# How to adjust selectivity of gas-permeable PDMS membranes for environmental applications?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, polymers, gas-phase-chemistry, separation-techniques, organosilicon-compounds

I have an idea about making an environmental sensor that uses a gas-permeable membrane (GMP) and how its probe could be submerged in a water source with an off the shelf gas sensor.

So far, my research has pointed me to using polydimethylsiloxanes (PDMS), but I am not able to get a straight answer on several aspects of GPMs from the distributers and manufacturers on one specific question I have. From what I understand, these membranes can be tuned by changing the thickness to increase or optimize permeability for certain gasses.

Is it possible to tune them to a specific set of gases, or to use a single membrane that blocks moisture but allows at least ammonia, carbon dioxide, oxygen and hydrogen sulfide gases through?

Would I be better served by membranes tuned to these specific gases, or is there a way to use a single membrane, tunable to the smallest of these $(\ce{O2}?),$ or maybe the largest $(\ce{NH3}?)$ that also has enough permeability for the other gasses, at least in a way that can be compensated for with time for their diffusion into the sensor chamber?

Any clarification or details about how this might work would be appreciated.